# Bluemix Nodejs FileTransferStep, documentation

Tags: node.js, sdk, ibm-cloud

I am a newbie to bluemix. I downloaded the client libraries. But I don't see API docs for Javascript. Where do I find that? How do I go about calling several of javascript functions which is neither in the nodejs client libs nor I could find it online?

Comment: Are you trying to use a specific service?  What client libraries are you referencing?  Can you include a link and also describe what goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to use workscheduler. I have the nodejs libs but I don't find docs to see how I can interface with the workload object from the web application. For example I want to make a call to WorkloadService with credentials. Where is documentation for supplying the parameters? Or how can I use FileTransferStep object ? Is there examaples for that. The client libs doesn't include the FileTransfer . Thanks Mariano

Answer (score 1):

about the Workload service call you have to edit your package.json file
to add a dependency on the iws-light module using an https link, as follows

```
"dependencies": {
    "iws-light": "https://start.wa.ibmserviceengage.com/bluemix/iws-light.tgz"
}
```

then you have to open your shell, go to the root of your app and run:

```
npm install
```

after this you can require the Workload Scheduler service in your application:

```
var ws = require("iws-light");
```

and create a connection to Bluemix:

```
    //retrieve service URL from Bluemix VCAP_SERVICES...
    var wsConn;
    if(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
        wsConn = ws.createConnection();
    } else {
        //...or set it on your own(if you're working in local)
        var url = "your workload scheduler url";
        wsConn = ws.createConnection(url);
    }

    //retrieve cloud agent 
    var agentName;
    wsConn.getCloudAgent(function(data) {
        agentName = data;
    });

    //set your timezone
    wsConn.setTimezone({timezone: "Europe/Rome"}, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

now you're ready to use the lib and create a process
and add to it a FileTransferStep:

```
    //create a process
    var process = new ws.WAProcess("ProcessName", "This process transfer a file every day from local to remote server");

    //supported operations are ws.steps.FileTransferStep.OperationDownload or ws.steps.FileTransferStep.OperationUpload
    var operation = ws.steps.FileTransferStep.OperationUpload;


    //create FileTransferStep
    var ftStep = new ws.steps.FileTransferStep(agentName, operation);

    //supported protocols are AUTO, FTP, FTPS, SSH, WINDOWS;
    ftStep.setProtocol(ws.steps.FileTransferStep.ProtocolAuto);

    //set local file
    var local = {
        path: "local file path",
        user: "local username",
        password: "local password"
    };
    ftStep.setLocalFile(local.path, local.user, local.password);

    //set remote file
    var remote = {
        path: "remote file path",
        user: "remote username",
        password: "remote password",
        server: "remote server"
    };
    ftStep.setRemoteFile(remote.server, remote.path, remote.user, remote.password);

    //the binary mode flag: true if it uses FTP binary mode
    var binaryMode = true;
    the passive mode flag: true if it uses FTP passive mode
    var passiveMode = true;
    //set timeout
    var timeout = 5;
    ftStep.setMode(binaryMode, passiveMode , timeout);

    //add FileTransferStep to the process
    process.addStep(ftStep);

    //create a trigger
    var trigger = new ws.TriggerFactory.everyDayAt(1, 7, 30);

    //add Trigger to the process
    process.addTrigger(trigger);

    process.tasklibraryid = "your task library id";

    //create and enable process
    wsConn.createAndEnableProcess(process, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(error);
        } else{
            console.log("process created and enabled");
        }
    });
```

The code above creates a process using a file transfer step from node.js code, however I'm not sure if this is what you actually need.
If you can explain the scenario you are trying to implement, I can be more precise about which is the best way to implement this scenario using Workload Scheduler service.

Regards,
Gabriele